# Rails: Form Helper not saving params correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters, controller

I'm working on a Rails app which allows users to view and create animals. Users can add in an animal's name and "range", which consists of the following:

models/Animal.rb

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :range
    validates :name, presence:true, length: {minimum:1}
    validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

models/Range.rb

```
class Range < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :animals
end
```

seeds.rb

```
ranges = [
{id: 1, name: "land"},
{id: 2, name: "sea"},
{id: 3, name: "air"},
{id: 4, name: "underground"}
]

animals = [
{id: 1, name: "dolphin", range_id: 2, range: "sea"},
{id: 2, name: "ant", range_id: 4, range: "underground"},
{id: 3, name: "eagle", range_id: 3, range: "air"}
]
```

range.id/animal.range_id and range.name and animal.range are connected through a foreign key and associations.

Here is my current animals_controller.rb

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @animals = Animal.all
    if params[:search]
      @animal = Animal.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @animals = Animal.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

  end

  def show
    @animal = Animal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @animal = Animal.new
  end

  def create
    # render plain: animal_params[:animal].inspect
    @animal = Animal.new(animal_params)

    if(@animal.save)
      redirect_to @animal
  end

  private def animal_params
    params.require(:animal).permit(:id, :name, :range, :range_id)
  end

end
```

Now here's the issue. The form helper I'm using for Animal.new has a select box that should automatically save the animal's range id AND range name. However, it saves the range name as a direct link to the range/show page instead.

```
<h1> Add Animal </h1>

<%= form_for :animal, url: animals_path do |f| %>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :name %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.label :range_name %> <br>
     <%= f.select :range_id, options_for_select(Range.all.collect { |range| [range.name, range.id]}), {}, class: 'form-control', include_blank: 'Please Select' %>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
    <p>
    <% end %>
```

So when I go to save a new animal, I get something like this. The range should say "land", not just save as a link to the range/show page.

```
Name: cat
range: range/1
```

I need it to say "land" instead. What am I doing wrong here? I suspect it has to do with the form helper but I can't find a definitive answer.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the models for Range and Animal. Also if Range is its own model you should normalize your DB by only having `range_id` in the Animal table, and any reference to that range would look it up in the Range table and get it's name via something like @range.name.

Comment: thanks @Beartech I edited those in just now

Comment: First thing I see is I think your Animal should `belongs_to :range`.

Comment: What is the value of `range` saved in database? Is the problem with creation of animal or with display of animal? Can you show the code for show page of animal? Can you also include server logs for the create request in your question?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you should be setting just the `range_id` in the animal model:

```
<%= f.label :rang_id, 'Range' %> <br>
<%= collection_select(:animal, :range_id, Range.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => 'Please select'}, class: 'form-control' ) %>
```

Also I think you want your Animal.rb to have the relation:

```
belongs_to :range
```

As noted in the comments above the problem might be what code you are using to display the range. If you add your web server log of the `save` call, and show your html.erb code for the display of `range`.